# Scala reduce returning different data type

Tags: scala

I am starting in Scala from Java,

At this moment I am trying to solve simple algorithms, basically, a conversor between `hh:mm` to mins to try as many scala features as possible. My code right now is this (It works)

```
def hourToMins(time : String):String =
  time.split(':').reduce(((a:String, b: String)=> a.toInt * 60 + b.toInt + ""))
```

However, if I remove the `+ ""` at the very end and also change the return type of the function to Int, doesnt work

```
def hourToMins(time : String):Int=
  time.split(':').reduce(((a:String, b: String)=> a.toInt * 60 + b.toInt ))
```

> ```
> found   : (String, String) => Int  
> required: (Any, Any) => Any
> ```

and even if I change it, adding an explicit conversion to Int like

```
def hourToMins(time : String):Int=
  time.split(':').reduce(((a:String, b: String)=> (a.toInt * 60 + b.toInt ).toInt)
```

it seems that this version also expects the two parameters to be Int :(

```
def hourToMins(time : String):Int=
   time.split(':').reduce[Int](((a:String, b: String)=> a.toInt * 60 + b.toInt ))
```

doesn't make it work.

What is the right way to do this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

Your list items have a different type than the result. The `reduce` function does not allow this, but `foldLeft` does. You just need `0` as the start value.

```
"01:01".split(':').foldLeft(0) {
    (a, b) => a * 60 + b.toInt
}
```

This returns 61.

Answer (score 7):

I would do things step after step.

So first do the type conversion then do the reduce.

```
def hourToMins(time : String): Int = 
    time.split(':')
        .map(s => s.toInt)
        .reduce(((h, m) => h * 60 + m))
```

Comment: Or even just `time.split(":").map(_.toInt).reduce(_ * 60 + _)`.